# How to reduce the file size of an image while keeping the same dimensions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, file-size, save

My goal is to create a Kindle Cover and upload it following Amazon recommendations.

The Cover Should Be:

**MAXIMUM**: `Width:1563px;     Height:2500px;   JPEG up to 127KB`

**MINIMUM**: `Width:625px;      Height:1000px;   JPEG up to 127KB`

I found a Powerpoint template that helps me to create Kindle covers.
However the size of it is: `541px x 864px` and `107KB`. So, I resized the template to Kindle standards, but now I have a picture
that is `1563px x 2500px` and `731KB`.

Using Photoshop and Save for Web I can turn the quality option to low.
The result of it is: `1563px x 2500px` and `198KB`.
It's still too heavy/large for Amazon standards.

**How can I reduce the file size further without making the image dimensions smaller?**

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you don't use the maximum size allowed, and instead go for something a bit smaller instead.

Depending on how complex your image is, a bigger size will definitely require a loss in quality. Your true limit in this case is the 127Kb. My reasoning is: You should aim for the maximum quality you can get without passing that weight.

So if you want to keep the **width/height ration of 1.6**, you can go for **1000x1600px** and the cover will still look good and have no visible quality loss. In my opinion, a 127Kb and 1563x2500px image is simply very, very difficult to achieve without completely ruining the quality.

Comment: Yisela, You are right! My only limit must be the 127Kb and adjust the rest for that. Is there a way to set in advance Photoshop to render the images with the 127Kb that I need? **MANY MANY THANKS!**

Comment: @Ronaldo I'm not aware of any, but maybe you could ask it as a new question as I'm sure there must be 'creative ways' of achieving that :). I would do it by re-sizing and saving for web, trying to keep the JPG quality at around 75-80%.

Answer (score 0):

Image > Image Size > then drop the resolution.

There's a read out at the top that tells you the pixel dimension. So basically can change it to an accepted size while choosing the best quality.

Comment: Crejus, Many Thanks.I have tried already what you said but without success.

Comment: Dropping the resolution (AKA the pixel dimensions) will work, of course, but will drastically reduce the quality as now the pixels all have to be 'stretched'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you will use that image but reducing colors can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file have to be saved in a specific format? Maybe you experiment saving in different formats seeing how some are lossy and may reduce the file size. Try JPG instead of PNG.